# Creating global variable from submodule available in entire module

Tags: python, module

Suppose I have three files inside a directory that is called `mymod`. The three files are `__init__.py`, `sm1.py`, `sm2.py`. The content of the modules are:

`__init__.py`

```
import sm1
import sm2
global _defaults
```

`sm1.py`

```
global _defaults
class get_defs:
    color='blue'
    number=10    
_defaults = get_defs()
```

`sm2.py`

```
def printdefs():
    print _defaults.color
    print _defaults.number
```

So, what I am trying to do is set a class inside submodule `sm1` called `_defaults` that can be accessed from any other place in the module or submodules, so that submodule `sm2` can also access and print that class. I thought this setting would work, but when I run

```
import mymod
mymod.sm2.printdefs()
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: global name '_defaults' is not defined
```

Any suggestions as how to do that (and why this isn't working?)

P.S.:

The reason I want a global variable instead of just setting some variable to be imported is that I want to be able for the user to do this:

```
>>> import mymod
>>> mymod.sm2.printdefs()
'blue'
10
>>> mymod._defaults.color='red'
>>> mymod.sm2.printdefs()
'red'
10
```

So, working with global variables is the only I thought I could work like this.

Thank you.

Comment: That's not really how python is intended to work. This seems more like the rails autoloader. Which, having worked with rails, is a terrible thing.

Comment: Can you refer me to a "preferred" way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

`global` is not how you do that. `sm1` should just set the variable, then all the other modules should just import it.

sm1.py:

```
class get_defs:
    color='blue'
    number=10 
_defaults = get_defs()
```

sm2.py

```
import sm1
def printdefs():
    print sm1._defaults.color
    print sm1._defaults.number
```

But really I'm not sure why you have a global for this rather than some kind of factory method, or class. If you can give more details about the actual project that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank for the attempt. This is pretty close I guess, but please check out my edit as to what I want to accomplish.